# How to center align form elements in simple_form

Tags: html, css, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I am trying to center align all the form elements in a form built with simple_form so I created a .simple_form and filled with certain things like float, text-align, etc to center everything but it doesn't work

```
.simple_form {
    float: none;
    text-align : center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: auto;
}
/*
.simple_form label {
  float: left;  
  width: 100px;   
  margin: 2px 10px; 
}  

.simple_form div.input {  
  margin-bottom: 10px;  
  margin: 2px 10px; 
}  

.simple_form div.boolean, .simple_form input[type='submit'] {  
  margin-left: 120px; 
  margin: 2px 10px; 
}  

.simple_form div.boolean label {  
  float: none;  
  margin: 0; 
  margin: 2px 10px; 
} 
*/
```

## HTML

```
<h1>Submit page </h1>
<%= simple_form_for Post.new  do |f| %> 
<%= f.input :title  %>
<%= f.input :blurb %> 
<%= f.input :funding_goal %>
<%= f.input :funding_duration %>   
<%= f.button :submit %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: use <center> tag but its not supported in HTML 5.

Comment: What is the HTML that's getting generated?

Comment: do you have a working example somwhere? or a http://jsfiddle.net with your code? also `position:auto` is not a valid css style. you may need to apply styles to it's parent container in order to make this work

Comment: Please provide us with a jsfiddle, so we can see the html and css code working

Comment: I have updated the code with the form in html whose elements i am trying to center align

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/gbgB4/42/)

Give `display:inline-block` to your input tags.

So, CSS Will be:

```
.simple_form {
    float: none;
    text-align : center;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.simple_form .input-box {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.simple_form input {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 2px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML Should be:

```
<form class="simple_form">
  <div class="input-box">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```